# When not to use GUID primary?

Tags: c#, sql-server, guid

I need to keep a record the token error response there are only 2 types of errors.

"RequestError" and "SystemError"

Since these errors do not change, why use GUID as the primary key, why cant I just store them error as "RequestError" and "SystemError"?

(My work colleague said we should just store it as unique identifiers, because everything else is stored as as unique identifiers hmm if we change these errors to something else later it be easy! hmm but they dont change?)

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.  First of all, these are _really_ unhelpful error messages, so I'm not entirely clear on the value of persisting them.  Second, GUIDs don't make for very good primary keys in general (or, more specifically, they don't make for very good clustered indexes).  Third, how relational/normalized does this data really need to be?  If an error type changes someday in the future, should that _really_ change all of the historical error messages?  I wouldn't think so.

Comment: @David I agree with you (and would never choose GUIDs for a primary key), but this was one of the reasons they introduced `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Indeed, and when I find an implementation of that which I like I'll be sure and use it :)  One problem I have with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is that it's machine-specific (even boot-specitic).  So the GUIDs are only sequential if they're generated on the same machine (perhaps even without rebooting).  Yet, the primary reason for using GUIDs is that they're global across machines.  If all my of data has to stay on one host, I don't need a GUID.

Comment: @David I agree, just pointing out what it overcomes. It still might be worthwhile in a situation where you need to generate unique IDs across multiple machines but never actually need to merge the data. Because they're in a different sequence on the other machine, who cares? The sequential nature is for local reasons, not global. My preference is identity ranges or an additional column, but hey, some people prefer fat indexes, just like some people prefer ORM over procedures or VB over C#.

Answer (score 2):

based on how I interpreted your (title) question, I would suggest having a read of http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

it's a short read and has a list of pros / cons, I tend to disagree that guids don't make for very good primary keys (or more so I feel it's a little to general as a statement)

I think if you're records are either "RequestError" or "SystemError" a guid could be surplus to requirement and if the table is to hold a large number of records a simple int primary key may be more efficient.

also there is a link to http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html which has a larger set of pros/ cons